# Polymerfire Firebase Firestore mixin - sorting

Tags: firebase, polymer, google-cloud-firestore, dom-repeat

I have a Polymer property using Polymerfire Firestore mixin and a dom-repeat:

```
        mySections: {
                    type: Array,
                    collection: '/users/{user.uid}/sections',
                    query: (q, el) => {
                             q = q.orderBy('sectionName')
                             return q;
                           }
                  }


<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{mySections}}" as="Section" index-as="SectionIndex">

    {{Section.sectionName}}

</template>
```

However, it's not sorting on sectionName? What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something here? Thanks.

Comment: Your data is where located. In firestore or Realtime database ? And specify more detail about database structure.

Comment: Data is located in Firestore. Data structure is /users/{user.uid}/sections where sectionName is a field in sections collection.

Thanks.

Comment: As i understood you have read data with above codes but not sorted. Is it .?

Comment: Or you have no data also ? I think.

Comment: Yes, data is there but not sorted.

Comment: Where the heck have you found the firestore mixin that I can't find it?

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/branches